# What does "Charge density is non zero in the resistive medium" mean?

Tags: classical-electrodynamics

[image]
[image]
[image]

The above images were taken from 'Introduction to Electrodynamics', D.J. Griffiths.

I have difficulty in understanding what he means by the hint.
(here, s is the radial distance from the axis of the cylinder.)

"Because sigma is a function of position, Eqn 7.5 does not hold" --agreed, that was true for steady currents and uniform conductivity only

"The charge density is non zero in the resistive medium"-- what? where did that come from?

we haven't introduced any charges to the medium externally so where does the charge density come up from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> we haven't introduced any charges to the medium externally so where
>   does the charge density come up from?

In the problem description, it is specified that the cylinders are maintained at a potential difference $V$ so, in fact, charges must be introduced to the medium externally.

> "The charge density is non zero in the resistive medium"-- what? where
>   did that come from?

Start with Ohm's Law:

$$\mathbf{J} = \sigma(s)\, \mathbf{E}$$

Take the divergence of both sides and find that there is an extra term on the right hand side (due to the $s$ dependence of $\sigma$, it does not 'pass through' the divergence operator) in addition to the $\sigma(s)\nabla \cdot \mathbf{E} = \sigma(s) \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$ term.

For steady currents, the left hand side is zero by the continuity equation

$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{J} = -\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = 0$$
 and so, from the extra term due to the $s$ dependence of $\sigma$, the charge density isn't zero.